# Issue get the good value from Moment JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to set a default value according a date and add 2 years to this date.
The method works but I don't know why I can't access to the good value from the momentObject.
This is my code:

```
const getNextYearsDateWithDefaultValue = (date: string, nextYear: number = 2): Moment =>
    moment(date).add(2, 'years')

  const [recallDate, setRecallDate] = useState<moment.Moment>(moment())

  const [defaultValueRecall, setDefaultValueRecall] = useState<moment.Moment>(moment())

  const minDate = dateTime ? moment(dateTime[0].startDate) : moment()

  const recallDateHandler = (e: any) => {
    setRecallDate(moment(e))
    form.setValue(FormLabelsNames.RECALL, recallDate)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dateTime) {
      const dateAppointment = moment(dateTime[0].startDate)
      const newRecallValue = getNextYearsDateWithDefaultValue(dateAppointment.toString())
      setDefaultValueRecall(newRecallValue)
    }
  }, [dateTime])
`
```

```
<ThemedDatePicker
 label={t('recall')}
 control={form.control}
 placeholder={t('buttons.select')}
 name={FormLabelsNames.RECALL}
 dateFormat={'YYYY-MM-DD'}
 withoutMargin
 defaultValue={defaultValues?.recall ?? defaultValueRecall}
 disabled={isDisable}
 shouldCloseOnSelect
 popperClassName="themedDatePickerPopover"
 minDate={minDate}
 onFocus={() => recallDateHandler}
 />
```

And this is what I get in the console:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 'Sat May 06 2023 09:30:00 GMT-0400', _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d
: 
Tue May 06 2025 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (heure d’été de l’Est nord-américain) {}
_i
: 
"Sat May 06 2023 09:30:00 GMT-0400"
_isAMomentObject
: 
true
_isUTC
: 
false
_isValid
: 
true
_locale
: 
Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: 'Invalid date', _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(er|e)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf
: 
{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_z
: 
null
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I want to access to :
Tue May 06 2025 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (heure d’été de l’Est nord-américain) {}

But I get all the time: "Sat May 06 2023 09:30:00 GMT-0400"

Why don't I get the good value?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).